# SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException after upgrading database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have upgraded my database and it works perfectly on a few handsets. However, in others, i get SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException.

- I have included the android_metadata table in my database.
- I haven't changed any other part of the application for this update. So, there should be no problem with the queries.
- I use SQLite Expert to create my database.

Error Report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quant.aptitude/com.quant.aptitude.QuestionsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:838)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
at com.quant.aptitude.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.quant.aptitude.QuestionsActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at com.quant.aptitude.QuestionsActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
... 11 more
```

The code used for creating and upgrading the database

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(mDataBaseExist)
    {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();


    if(!mDataBaseExist) 
    { 
        this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        this.close(); 
        try  
        { 
            //Copy the database from assets 
            copyDataBase(); 
        }  
        catch (IOException mIOException)  
        { 
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
        } 
    } 
} 

private boolean checkDataBase() 
{ 
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
    return dbFile.exists(); 
} 

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int mLength; 
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
    { 
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
    } 
    mOutput.flush(); 
    mOutput.close(); 
    mInput.close(); 
} 

public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
{ 
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
    return mDataBase != null; 
} 

@Override 
public synchronized void close()  
{ 
    if(mDataBase != null) 
        mDataBase.close(); 
    super.close(); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {  
        try { 
            copyDataBase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            throw new Error("Error upgrading database"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Is there an error in the OnUpgrade method?

Comment: Please, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34418067/4283005

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will still need to add the SQL commands to create the empty tables in onCreate even though you plan to overwrite it.  Android is picky about schema mismatch when seeding databases like this.  Does your DB even get copied (can you see it in your SD after copyDatabase )? It won't be able to copy if the folder path doesn't exist which maybe isn't getting created because your onCreate is empty.

Comment: The database gets copied. First time after upgrading, I get the error. The next time when i open the application, it works well.