# SQlite Database onUpdate crashes

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My current code causes app crash after updating database from assets (i get database is malformed). I know where is the problem (because the table schema change) and I need to SELECT * and dump into the new database by storing in a temp location first, but really don't know how to implement this. Could you please help me with code?

Currently it is:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   try {
    copyDatabase();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new Error("Error copying database" + e.toString());
   }
}

public void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
   // Open your local db as the input stream
   InputStream myinput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

   // Path to the just created empty db
   String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

   // Open the empty db as the output stream
   OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

   // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int length;
   while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }

   // Close the streams
   myoutput.flush();
   myoutput.close();
   myinput.close();
}
```

btw App crashes on first application run, when I open it again everthing works fine. The problem doesn't appear also if user downloads the newest version, without having previous version.

Logcat:

```
06-28 17:11:54.456: E/SQLiteLog(25926): (11) database corruption at line 50987 of     [00bb9c9ce4]
06-28 17:11:54.456: E/SQLiteLog(25926): (11) statement aborts at 4: [select count(*) from Numerical] 
06-28 17:11:54.456: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(25926): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/com.xxx.yyy/databases/database.db
06-28 17:11:54.456: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(25926): deleting the database file: /data/data/com.xxx.yyy/databases/database.db
06-28 17:11:54.456: E/AndroidRuntime(25926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 17:11:54.456: E/AndroidRuntime(25926): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity                ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.PuzzleActivity}:     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat?

Comment: sure. it's already there

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that this code is correct then try to change `DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`  if you hadn't do this 
and also try this :

```
  @Override
public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
```

Comment: thanks, I do exactly like above.. the problem is, that when I change database table schema, provided code crashes.

Comment: I think if you but your orginal code logcat whin it crash, it will help me and the others to help you

Comment: also there is an "write-error' in my answer chek  it again please

Comment: #1 i have updated my post with logcat
#2 changing database (adding/removing one of tables) and not updating DATABASE_VERSION also causes crash

Answer (score 0):

When you call copyDatabase() from the onUpgrade method, you are effectively overriding the existing database file. The problem is, that the onUpgrade method is called while the database is open, and modifying it causes an exception later.

The solution can be to set a flag in onUpgrade (like shouldUpgradeDatabaseFile = true) and execute the actual copy operation outside (e.g. in getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase()).